# Wrong emoji unicode

Tags: javascript, unicode, hex, emoji

When I want to convert this emoji: ‍️
I get only a part of the wanted unicode: `U+1f636` instead of `U+1F636U+200DU+1F32BU+FE0F`

I tried using `String.prototype.codePointAt(0).toString(16)`
But it give me `"1f636"` (not the thing I want)
In JavaScript

Comment: Emojis can be more than one code point

Comment: You need to map (or loop) through the codepoints.

Comment: Not only emojis can have more codepoints. Many other characters in many languages (and also symbols) may be composed by more codepoints. Unicode database has the property class "Mark", with combining marks, encircling marks. In addition Apple tend to prefer old Unicode preference: accented characters are coded with two (or more) codepoints (contrary Windows which prefers shortest coding). (and each font has own preference... things are converted back and forth too many times)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only partially there .. `String.prototype.codePointAt(0).toString(16)` will give you the correct Uni for the first codepoint ( index[0] ), but you'll need to map through ALL the codepoints that make up said emoji:

```js
const emoji = "‍️" 

const emoji_uni = "U+" + [...emoji].map(
   e => e.codePointAt(0).toString(16)
).join('+').toUpperCase()

console.log(emoji_uni)
```

Because your OP was specific -- I

1. added `toUppercase()`
2. pre-pended the string with `U+`
3. used `.join()` to join as a string and add your `+` denotations

Which will result in `U+1F636+200D+1F32B+FE0F`